# Automatically create tag based on the string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, tags, tagging

I am new to ruby on rails.

Lets say i have this text.. Ashley Cole and Cheryl Cole Split.

Is there a way to automatically tag this above text to Ashley Cole, Cheryl Code, ChelseaFC ( Ashley Cole plays football (Soccer) for that club.

Please help..

Also which is the best tagging gem available?

Looking forward for your help

Thanks

Gautam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i doubt any gem could do it decently. there are some external APIs like http://tagthe.net/ which you could use to tag your content in background.